# Slickgrid/Dataview without Primary Key

Tags: slickgrid, dataview

I am using SlickGrid/DataView for CRUD purposes. It is working fine. However, we have some of the tables which do not have primary key.

Q1: How can I use dataview for such tables? If not then am I left with using Slickgrid without dataview only OR I have another choice? Any example would be appreciated.

Q2: Does Dataview support composite primary keys? If yes, can anybody give me an example of using it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

SlickGrid requires at least the ID field, you can take whichever that could be named differently in your table and then alias it to "ID" but it has to be a UNIQUE id field because SlickGrid is using it for row naming and so on.

If you do not have a UNIQUE field and you really want to use composite primary keys, then I suggest you create a fake ID field which you simply increment by 1 each loop. A simple way is to do this while fetching the data, something similar to the following:

```
$sqlTable = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
$result = mysql_query($sqlTable,$connMySQL);

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $tabData[] = array( 
        "id" => $i++, 
        "column1" => $row['column1'],
        "column2" => $row['column2'] 
    );
}
```

Now if you do use a fake ID like I just said, this will give you some problems doing the CRUD (update, delete) since your ID is not real and point to nowhere... but there is a way to fix that too. 
By the way, you should split your question into 2 separate question since they are different subjects. I suggest you ask your CRUD subject in another question and that you provide some code so we can develop from there.